# Cannot register transform lynx_dump error log entries in Plone 4

Tags: plone

Currently one of Plone 4.1 instance.log is (mgirated from 3.3) gets messages like:

```
2012-07-09 17:40:38 ERROR PortalTransforms Cannot register transform lynx_dump, using BrokenTransform: Error
 Unable to find binary "lynx" in /Users/moo/tools/bin:/Users/moo/.zsh/bin:/opt/local/libexec/gnubin:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11/bin
```

1) Is this a real error (probably not)?

2) How to get rid of this messages?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not a real problem, unless you use the `lynx_dump` transform (nothing in stock Plone uses it, and other transforms provide `text/html` to `text/plain` too).

You have two options to deal with it:

1. Remove the `lynx_dump` transform. Go to the ZMI, find the `portal_transforms` tool, check the box by the `lynx_dump` entry, and hit the `[Delete]` button at the bottom of the form. This is harmless if you don't use the transform.
2. Install the `lynx` command. `port install lynx` should do.

Answer (score 1):

"Mostly Harmless"

you might want to install lynx anyway, just for kudos and old-times-sake But there are a few other transforms that do html-to-plaintext just as well. Then again, the Lynx transform does earn you kudos with some screenreaders for the otherwise-abled crowd, and it's not a drain on your resources. So apt-get install lynx, or whatever your OS of choice offers

Comment: Isn't html-to-plaintext transformation so simple that no third party applications should be involved?

Comment: @polyester Thanks for pointing out the screen-reader-support of Lynx, pretty good reason to use it.